# How do I let PHP echo "\n" as plain-text for javascript and not have the "\n" create a new line?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

PHP is echoing JavaScript (I'm using the jQuery library) something like this:

`echo 'var users = $("#add").val().split("\n");';`

However, the \n is creating a line break in what the echoed script looks like, and therefore breaking the JavaScript. Is there a way to circumvent this?
Many thanks!

Comment: As you have it escaped with single quotes, this should work unless you're passing it through some sort of output buffer and doing weird things there.  Can you paste the actual line of code?

Comment: "something like this"? You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\n` is an escape sequence meaning newline. Backslashes are the beginning of escape sequences, to output a backslash then write `\\`. So you want `\\n`. Other useful escape sequences include the quote: use `\"` to put a quote into the string instead of ending the string.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for this explanation. I knew there must have been a way, but I couldn't (for the life of me) find it online.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "var users = $(\"#add\").val().split(\"\\n\");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If you looking for this

```
echo "<script>alert('Line1\\\\nThis still in Line1')</script>";
```